# LPR/ANPR through keras and tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to do license plate recognition using keras and tensor flow but i don't know anything about it right now. Suggest me some online resources preferably online courses to recognize number plates using tensor flow.Right now i searched/started some deep Learning courses but they aren't coming to my part there are too many extra things.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @SafetyUp welcome to stack overflow. There are basically 2 steps you need to follow,

1. Training neural network on artificially generated data.
2. Fine-tuning neural network on real data.

for your question about license plate recognition, the following links may help you,
https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/
https://github.com/Dharun/Tensorflow-License-Plate-Detection